# Is it possible to publish push notification without creating "create application endpoint" in AWS SNS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I'm decided to use the AWS SNS service and new to this service
I'm creating a push notification module for my app in node.js using AWS SNS service, I am wondering why SNS service storing every device token i.e, createApplicatoinEndpoint before publishing push notification?

What is the exact use of "create application endpoint"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot publish notification without calling application endpoint
Here is the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-api.html) that explained in detail